# Buildfire - Camera Service Returns Null for Image

Tags: buildfire

In my **index.html** I have:

```
<head>
  <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.js"></script>
  <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire/services/camera/camera.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then inside of my react app I have:

```
buildfire.services.camera.getPicture({}, (err, image) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('image: ', image);
  }
})
```

When the function fires, half of the time the console.log of *image* will be *null*, half the time it will correctly launch the camera on my phone (testing inside of the previewer). I never run into issues where it errors. In order to get it to work I just keep restarting the previewer. It seems to be a 50/50 chance of working each time I load the previewer. Testing on an android galaxy s6.

Comment: This seems odd. You may have a race condition have you contacted your technical account manager to view your particular app?

Comment: @Daniel_Madain how is it a race condition? On the times it doesn't work, it doesn't load up my camera on my phone so the callback just assumes my image is null

Answer (score 0):

If you create a bare bones version of the plugin, without React or any other custom code, can you reproduce the issue? If so, share the code for this bare bones example plugin. Thanks.

Update: I created a bare bones plugin that utilizes the camera, and it seems to work fine when I use it on the Previewer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire/services/camera/camera.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="pic">
</body>
<script>
    buildfire.services.camera.getPicture({},
        function (err, imageData) {
            console.log('error', err);
            console.log('imageData', imageData);

            if (imageData) {
                document.getElementById("pic").src = imageData;
            }
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works but the second I wrap it with a function and try to call it with a button click I can't get it to work

Comment: Can you try wrapping your function and calling it with a button click?

Comment: That's odd; I did as you suggested and now am seeing similar behavior.